# How to 'override' a fieldset in magento?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I just added a second lastname field to magento's register form, and modified the method getName from `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer` so that it will include the second name everywhere the name is printed. It works everywhere except in the admin customer list, where a fieldset is read from the config.xml of `Mage_Customer`. My question is, how do I 'override' that fieldset from my custom module?

For the record, I already tried to put the `fieldset`tag inside my config.xml with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Traced the whole thing to `Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer_Collection`
where there is a method named `addNameToSelect()` that actually concatenates the whole name (Prefix, First, Middle, Lastname, Suffix), so what I wound up doing was overriding this specific method and adding my second last name there.

Code follows:

```
/**
 * Add Name to select
 *
 * @return Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer_Collection
 */
public function addNameToSelect()
{
    $fields = array();
    $customerAccount = Mage::getConfig()->getFieldset('customer_account');
    foreach ($customerAccount as $code => $node) {
        if ($node->is('name')) {
            $fields[$code] = $code;
        }
    }

    $adapter = $this->getConnection();
    $concatenate = array();
    if (isset($fields['prefix'])) {
        $concatenate[] = $adapter->getCheckSql(
            '{{prefix}} IS NOT NULL AND {{prefix}} != \'\'',
            $adapter->getConcatSql(array('LTRIM(RTRIM({{prefix}}))', '\' \'')),
            '\'\'');
    }
    $concatenate[] = 'LTRIM(RTRIM({{firstname}}))';
    $concatenate[] = '\' \'';
    if (isset($fields['middlename'])) {
        $concatenate[] = $adapter->getCheckSql(
            '{{middlename}} IS NOT NULL AND {{middlename}} != \'\'',
            $adapter->getConcatSql(array('LTRIM(RTRIM({{middlename}}))', '\' \'')),
            '\'\'');
    }
    $concatenate[] = 'LTRIM(RTRIM({{lastname}}))';

    //HERE I ADDED THE SECOND LAST NAME
    if (isset($fields['lastname2'])) {
        $concatenate[] = $adapter->getCheckSql(
            '{{lastname2}} IS NOT NULL AND {{lastname2}} != \'\'',
            $adapter->getConcatSql(array('\' \'','LTRIM(RTRIM({{lastname2}}))', '\' \'')),
            '\'\'');
    }


    if (isset($fields['suffix'])) {
        $concatenate[] = $adapter
                ->getCheckSql('{{suffix}} IS NOT NULL AND {{suffix}} != \'\'',
            $adapter->getConcatSql(array('\' \'', 'LTRIM(RTRIM({{suffix}}))')),
            '\'\'');
    }

    $nameExpr = $adapter->getConcatSql($concatenate);

    $this->addExpressionAttributeToSelect('name', $nameExpr, $fields);

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

David, you can override/modify the grid app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Customer\Grid.php and modify _prepareCollection to include your field in collection and use addColumn method to display the secondlast name.